# Difference between instantons and sphalerons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topological-field-theory, instantons, baryogenesis, leptogenesis

What is the difference between [instantons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instanton) and [sphalerons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphaleron)? If they are different, how do they violate baryon and lepton number in the standard electroweak theory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *sphaleron* is kind of the opposite of the instanton, and kind of the same. Let's make that statement precise:

An *instanton* is a local minimum of the action that [mediates vacuum tunneling](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/127880/50583) (link to an answer of mine how and why instantons do that). The *sphaleron* sits in-between the vacua, in a certain sense, it is the instanton "in the middle of tunneling":

Given an instanton configuration $A_\text{inst}$ on a 4-cylinder $(-\infty,\infty) \times S^3$, representing tunneling between two vacua at the spatial slices at $t = \pm \infty$ with Chern-Simons winding numbers differing by 1, the sphaleron is *vaguely* the field configuration $A(t = 0)$, and precisely the field configuration for which, at some time $t_0$, the winding number as the integral of the Chern-Simons form

$$ \int_{{t_0} \times S^3}\omega \equiv \int_{{t_0} \times S^3} \mathrm{tr}(F\wedge A - \frac{1}{3}A \wedge A \wedge A) $$

is exactly the mean of the winding numbers of the vacua at the ends.

The idea is that an instanton of winding number 1 mediates between vacua of winding numbers $k$ and $k+1$, and that the sphaleron is the field configuration "in the middle", with winding number $\frac{2k+1}{2}$. The reason this is interesting is because, for example, in the electroweak theory, the bosonic potential part of the action is (of course) minimal for the vacuum/instanton configurations, and *maximal* for the sphaleron configuration. That's why the sphaleron is called that (it's Greek for *slippery thing*) - it may slip down into either vacuum configuration because it is sitting in a metastable extremum of the potential.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of a sphaleron. So, following your conceptual explanation, would a Coleman de Lucia instanton (e.g. tunneling from de Sitter to Minkowski) be a sphaleron at some stage?

Comment: @JamalS: I have no idea, because the CdL instanton is in a slightly different setting (string theory/theories of gravity).

Comment: @ ACuriousMind - The physical mechanism by which instantons violate fermion number is tunneling. But what is the mechanism by which sphalerons violate the fermion number?

Comment: @SRS: I've never understood this kind of phrasing. Quantumly, you find that the symmetry that usually would conserve baryon/lepton number is anomalous, and that its non-conservation is exactly the Chern class/winding number. I honestly do not understand how one can meaningfully talk about the *process* that creates that anomaly, since it is simply the result of the transformation of the path integral measure under the symmetry transformation.

Comment: @SRS in sphaleron processes the energy barrier is crossed from above the barrier (as opposed to tunneling) through thermal fluctuations.