# How are the vacua of Yang-Mills theory connected by or changed by instanton effects?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topology, yang-mills, classical-field-theory, instantons

**Warning:** This question is based on poor/immature understanding of instantons and the vacuum structure of the SU(N) Yang-Mills theory.

Different vacua of the SU(2) Yang-Mills theory and the corresponding inequivalent instanton field configurations are labeled by a number $n$, called the *Pontryagin index*.

1. How do the instantons evolve in time to change a vacuum labeled by $n=n_1$, for example, to another vacuum $n=n_2$?
2. Since instantons are also labeled by the integer $n$, which instanton is responsible for the above vacuum transition i.e., from $n=n_1$ to $n=n_2$?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127879/50583