# Is Yang-Mills Instanton number zero?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, yang-mills, instantons, boundary-terms

I am studying Yang-Mills instanton.

Suppose we have an action in $R^4$
\begin{equation}
S=\int_{M} Tr(F\wedge *F)
\end{equation}
where $F=dA+A\wedge A$.

The instanton number $k$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
k=\int_{M} Tr(F\wedge F)
\end{equation}
Now it can be shown
\begin{equation}
Tr(F\wedge F)=d\bigg[Tr(A\wedge dA+\frac{2}{3}A\wedge A \wedge A)\bigg]
\end{equation}
Applying Stokes' theorem, we have $k=0$?

I think I made a mistake. But what's wrong with my calculation?

Comment: Just to highlight the issue, [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem) doesn't give that this is 0 if $\partial M$ is nonzero. The answer below nicely expands on this.

Comment: Other users think that you are leaving out a factor of $1/24\pi^2$, is this the case?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/127880/50583

Answer (score 2):

In QFT, we are used to ignoring boundary terms because they don't affect the perturbative dynamics, but they need not be $0$.

In fact, if one performs the boundary integral on $\partial M = S^3$ (after approprietly Wick rotating to euclidean time) it can be shown that the boundary integral

\begin{equation}
    k \propto \int_{\partial M}Tr(A\wedge dA+\frac{2}{3}A\wedge A \wedge A),
\end{equation}

is independant of the radius $R$ of the 3-sphere. It's not too hard to accept that this integral will depend only on the relationship between the gauge group $G$ and the boundary. 
I won't go into details here (an excelent reference is [David Tong's lecture notes on Gauge Theory](http://damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html)), but the instanton number is characterised by $\pi_3(G)$.

From a physical point of view, the instanton number is intepreted as the class of mapping from the boundary 3-sphere into the gauge group. Field configuration belonging in different classes cannot be continuously mapped onto one another.
Hope this helps a little.